# Need computer hooked up to ISP modem be able to access devices on separate network subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

Let me first explain my scenario.

I have my ISP's modem that is set to give IPs 192.168.1.x and so on. Directly to this modem, I have a computer hooked up set with a static IP 192.168.1.100. With the same ISP modem I then have a Xiaomi Router connected with guest internet turned on.

The Xiaomi router is giving IPs like this 192.168.31.x (as this router is not set up as an extender) to devices that connected wirelessly to the "normal" network and IPs like this 192.168.31.x to devices connected to the "guest" network.

In the same network, I then have 3 chromecast audio devices that are set up to connect to the Xiaomi router's "normal" network.

I want that whoever is in the office, connects to the guest network to access the internet so this way, people visiting can't control whatever is being played on the chromecast devices.

The idea is to have the one computer connected to the ISP's modem to cast audio to the chromecast devices that are connected to the Xiaomi's normal network. And this is where my problem is. Given that this computer has an IP of 192.168.1.x, the chromecasts are not found as these have IPs similar to 192.168.31.x.

I was originally thinking of changing my ISP modem's IP to give IPs starting from 192.168.31.x (if this makes any sense at all) or perhaps to a number higher than 31 but it seems that the modem itself does not allow this as there is no option to change the IP.

I also tried to change the Xiaomi's IP address to something like 192.168.1.x so it's on the same level as the ISP modem but for some reason, this router was giving an error - unfortunately I'm not sure what the error was as it was in Chinese and I wasn't able to translate at that time.

Can anyone please suggest a way to have this setup but also have the main computer able to find the chromecast devices please? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have the capability to change which subnet the modem assigns to devices.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound for the reply. Are there any other alternative ways of going about this?